# How to build vertical tab sets in WPF?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

How to build vertical tab sets in WPF? The tabs will stack up in top-to-bottom just like the "Properties" of a project shown in visual studio.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Have you tried the [`TabControl.TabStripPlacement` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.tabstripplacement.aspx)?

> The following example creates a tab control that positions the tabs on the left side.

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10">
  <TabItem Name="fontweight" Header="FontWeight">
    <TabItem.Content>
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
        FontWeight property information goes here.
      </TextBlock>
    </TabItem.Content>
  </TabItem>

  <TabItem Name="fontsize" Header="FontSize">
    <TabItem.Content>
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
        FontSize property information goes here.
      </TextBlock>
    </TabItem.Content>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 15):

You should try this code:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                                </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on rkirac's answer above. If you don't want to create a global style, you can put the same stuff inside `TabControl.ItemContainerStyle` that will only affect the `TabControl` in question. Following is a simple example:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
  <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
      <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
          <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```