# WPF - divide main window to parts

Tags: c#, wpf

I wondered if someone could help me. I'm new to WPF and am currently writing a desktop application, but i want to divide main window to parts each part in new window .
I have one window have many icons in it .
I want to select one icon from them and open it a new part . something like a vertical tab control .

Comment: What? Sorry it is impossible to tell what you are asking from your current question. Consider adding images, code, ...

Comment: I have one window have many icons in this i want to select one icon from them and open it a new part .

Comment: Still unclear. You are stating in your question it should open in a new window? And now you say in a different part? Are you searching for something like a vertical tab control?

Comment: yes i want something like a vertical tab control .

Comment: Then check this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953286/how-to-build-vertical-tab-sets-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the main thread you popup the 1 st window and in its Loaded event you open  another window
with show() method, not with showdialog () then position (location prop or something) the 2 windows next to each other

hope this helps

Comment: thanks i find the soultion from your advice