# Bootstrap css style of vertical tab control for WPF?

Tags: wpf

I'm looking for a bootstrap CSS style of a vertical tab control, like at this page:

[image]

https://dbtek.github.io/bootstrap-vertical-tabs/demo.html

If I'm going to do it myself, what WPF control should I begin with as the base class? (I don't think the WPF tabcontrol should be a starting point because the styles are so different)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build vertical tab sets in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953286/how-to-build-vertical-tab-sets-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-style the `TabControl` and the `TabItems` to look like you want. It may require some effort though.

You can right-click on a `TabControl` in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose `Edit Template`->`Edit a Copy` to copy the default style into your XAML markup and then edit it as per your requirements. `Edit Additional Templates`->`Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)` will do the same thing for the `TabItem` container.

Also note that you can set the `TabStripPlacement` property of the `TabControl` to `Left` to change the position of the tabs.